Django test views code:error database "test_postgres" already exists
I want to test my website and I created a tests folder inside my app and created files for testing models…, I ran the test URLs and it was successful but I faced a problem with views, models, and forms tests, “database "test_postgres" already exists Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_postgres', or 'no' to cancel”, I’m afraid to delete something important so how can fix the problem ( I used Supabase hosted my Postgres database).
I tried to ran the views and models but I faced this problem what should I do to solve this problem

Does this answer your question? Django testing: Got an error creating the test database: database "database_name" already exists

Kindly share your test case function or class where the error is coming from, the views you want to test, and if possible, the models.py.
Without the above requests I mentioned, we are likely not going to trace the error and help you out ASAP. Kindly wrap your code with this formatted markdown syntax ```py  `` when you are done.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
